# How can i set body to be 100% and still expand past page height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to expand the body's height to be beyond 100% of the page.

If i set

```
body, html { height: 100%; 
             background-color: darkbrown; }
.container { height: 100%; }
```

then if the content inside container goes beyond 100% it overflows and the color isnt saved. The problem here is that unless I remove the height or change it to min-height it will continue this behavior. What can I do to change this? Keep in mind that setting height % is necessary to create sticky footer.

Here's a fiddle with a better expample:

http://jsfiddle.net/hfqGu/1/

ive tried setting overflow to auto but with no avail.

Comment: If you make a fiddle, please make it as simple as possible to explain your problem. This fiddle's CSS (and also the html) is for a large proportion unnecessary code I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height:100%` specified for the `body` tag.

Comment: Removing the height in body would mean i cant set the .main-section height to a percentage making a sticky footer more difficult.

Comment: @Snowfiring remove this from your stylesheet `html, body, .wrapper, .container { height: 100%; }`. Don't specify the height for the lop level container to 100%. When you give 100%, the height of the browser window gets applied to the divs. So I think if you remove the above code and make the footer sticky it would be fine.